# How does this MOSFET soft distortion circuit work?

Tags: mosfet

I have made this simple circuit in LTSpice. I was trying to make a soft distortion circuit for an audio effect, it seems to work very well, but I don't know why.

[image]

It only works when the P-MOSFET has the drain and source the other way round from normal use. Maybe the internal diodes have something to do with the distortion.

Am I using the MOSFETs outside of their normal range?

Is it likely to give similar results with real components, without frying them?

Comment: Note that you are using ideal FET models which usually are pretty far away from anything you can find in real life.

Comment: *Is it likely to give similar results with real components* No because as PlasmaHH mentions, you're using simplified MOSFET models. You will not be able to buy any components which behave in a similar way. Discrete MOSFETs you can buy behave radically different from the ones you're simulating with. Also you will be unable to find complementary NMOS/PMOS pairs. This is a nice **theoretical** circuit, it has no value in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

Check what current is flowing through the mosfets when V1 is set to 0V. You might be surprised to find that it is several amps making it unattractive for audio use especially if used in a battery powered pedal. If you try and add resistance to reduce this current you will likely linearize the desirable characteristic into something less desirable.

So, is this technique used at all - every common or garden CMOS chip uses this and, when run linearly give this characteristic: -

[image]
[image]

Pictures taken from [this](https://allthingsvlsi.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/inverter-operating-points/) site.

Comment: Andy, I will look into using a CMOS inverter. Do you know of any other circuit that will give me the curve I was getting in my simulation? Btw I'm getting 100 amps at 0 volts ouch!

Comment: @NickCollier I felt your pain heehee. No, CMOS has this technique  pretty much wrapped up - look for unbuffered CMOS though.

Comment: This is an interesting circuit, not so simple.  simhttp://www.electronics-eetimes.com/news/filter-wizard-just-add-transistor-or-clipping-me-softly/page/0/2

Comment: I think the link is bust?

Comment: Try searching 'filter wizard clipping me softly' that's how I found it

Comment: You can do the same with diodes and resistors across an op-amp.